# Can sunlight kill seeds

Tags: seeds, germination

I accidentally left a plastic container full of vegetable seeds under direct sunlight for several hours.  The plastic container is translucent and became quite hot (above 60C, i.e. 140F) and uncomfortable to hold. The seeds themselves are packaged in small white envelopes.  It's hard to say if the seeds also reached that temperature.

Are the seeds likely damaged/dead now?

Comment: What kinds of vegetables?

Comment: Quite a few different kinds:  Swiss Chards, bok choy, lettuce, turnip, muster...

Answer (score 1):

Heat is definitely a factor in viability. Some species more than others: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=seed+viability+heat&ia=web           https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261617200_The_Effect_of_Temperature_on_the_Viability_Of_Weed_Seeds_in_Compost
Looks like the only way you'll find out is to try them and see.